# What is the best way to handle user credentials across controllers in Spring Boot MVC

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I would like to move up below code from a controller to a global place. Where this username and role can be stored and shared across controllers, avoiding re-execution of this code in every request.

```
 @RequestMapping(path = {""})
    public String clientHome(Model model, Principal principal){
        ..........
        ..........

        KeycloakAuthenticationToken token = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) principal;
        KeycloakPrincipal keycloakprincipal=(KeycloakPrincipal)token.getPrincipal();
        KeycloakSecurityContext session = keycloakprincipal.getKeycloakSecurityContext();
        AccessToken accessToken = session.getToken();
        String role = ((KeycloakAuthenticationToken) principal).getAuthorities().toString().replace("ROLE_","");

        model.addAttribute("username", accessToken.getGivenName() +" "+accessToken.getFamilyName());
        model.addAttribute("role", role);

        return "home";
    }
```